# Windows Phone 7 Taking Photo

Tags: windows-phone-7, cameracapturetask

I am developing Windows Phone 7 application (7.0) and want to take photo without using CameraCaptureTask. There will be a button on main screen and it will take photo by clicking it instantly. Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows Phone 7.0 you can only use the CameraCaptureTask for this. You have to upgrade on Mango if you need more functionality.